# Reliable Margin of Error for Float -> String -> Float Conversion?

Tags: php, floating-point, precision, floating-accuracy

I have a `float` value that I need to store as a string in PHP and then compare later after casting back into a float.

Due to the conversion I know that relying on equality would be a mistake, as there's potential for a loss of precision, so I'm doing something like the following:

```
if (abs((float)$string_value - $float_value) < 0.001) { echo "Values are close enough\n"; }
```

Now, while a margin for error of `0.001` should be fine for my immediate purposes, it got me wondering; what is the smallest margin of error that I can reliably/safely use?

I realise that the safe margin of error will change with the size of the float (i.e- larger values have less or even no fractional precision), so an answer should probably account for this.

So to put it another way; given a float value that I want to store in base 10 and read back, how can I reliably decide what my margin of error should be such that I can reasonably confirm that the two values are the same?

Unfortunately the values I'm handling **must** be stored in plain decimal form, so my usual go-to of packing them as a network order 64-bit integer is not an option here ☹️

**EDIT**: To clarify; please assume that my question is about handling arbitrarily sized floats; the example code I've given is for a recent case where I'm handling floats within a limited range, so setting the margin of error manually is fine, but I'd like to be able to handle floats of any magnitude in future.

Comment: We need more information on how you're converting to string (and back). With the right conversions, you don't need any margin of error at all. For example, if you take a finite IEEE 754 binary64 floating-point number and convert it to decimal using at least 17 significant digits (using some form of round-to-nearest for the conversion), you get a decimal string that converts back to the _exact_ float you started with, with no error.

Comment: Unfortunately I think I'm limited to PHP's default float to string conversion; I'm actually storing the value in memcached at present, but this seems to be how PHP's memcached module handles floats.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in Mark Dickinson's comment, it is possible to convert a floating-point number to a string and back *without losing precision*. This only works if

- you use enough significant decimal digits (17 for IEEE doubles)
- the conversions are accurate (i.e. they're guaranteed to convert to the nearest number)

From a quick look, it seems that casting a double `$f` to a string in PHP, either implicitly or with `(string) $f`, only uses 14 significant digits, so this method isn't accurate enough. But you can use `sprintf` with a `%.16e` conversion specifier to get 17 significant digits. So after the following roundtrip

```
$s  = sprintf("%.16e", $f);
$f2 = (double) $s;
```

`$f2` should equal `$f` exactly unless PHP uses suboptimal algorithms internally.

Note that the `%e` conversion specifier uses scientific (exponential) notation. If you need plain decimal strings, you can use the `%f` specifier and calculate the required number of digits after the decimal point using `log10`:

```
if ($f != 0) {
    $prec = 16 - floor(log10(abs($f)));
    if ($prec < 0) $prec = 0;
}
else {
    $prec = 0;
}
$s = sprintf("%.${prec}f", $f);
```

This can produce extremely long strings for very small or large numbers, though.

It would probably require a huge amount of research to tell the whether  these methods are completely reliable, and if not what the maximum error is. It all depends on several implementation details like PHP version, underlying C library, etc.

Another idea is to compare the string representations instead of floating-point values:

```
# Assuming $string_value was also converted with float_to_string
if ($string_value == float_to_string($float_value)) {
    echo "Values are close enough\n";
}
```

This should be reliable as long as you stick to the same PHP version.

If you must compare floating-point numbers, it often makes more sense to compare the relative error. See [Bruce Dawson's excellent blog](https://randomascii.wordpress.com/2012/02/25/comparing-floating-point-numbers-2012-edition/) for more details.